# how to link a ProtonMail address to a website contact form with React

Tags: javascript

How to link proton email to my existing website to receive client inquiries.
Is it possible with the frontend stack only? Or do I need to use the backend for this?

Answer (score 2):

For that you would require a library that allows you to connect to the email account and send emails via some API. I would suggest putting that logic in the backend. There are many libraries out there, the one that I have used for a NodeJS backend is [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/), but it depends on the framework/language you chose for backend.

Your inquiries could follow this workflow:

Web user request (HTTP call) -> Backend API (some controller using nodemailer/your lib) -> Send an email with the content.